# issues with google-dfp %%PATTERN:key%%

Tags: google-dfp

Do anyone know how DFP macros work ?

in que banner I have code that look like:

```
  var marque = '%%PATTERN:make%%';
  var modele = '%%PATTERN:model%%';
```

The macros are not being replaced. I wondered if it's not because my variable are not the same ? should I write it like that ?

```
  var make = '%%PATTERN:make%%';
  var model = '%%PATTERN:model%%';
```

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, but as with everything: test it :-). Are you sure you're sending make and model to DFP when you define your slots? .setTargeting('make', 'BMW') and .setTargeting('model', '1 Series'). Read more about it: https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/2376981?hl=en (click on Pattern match macro)

Comment: thanks for the answer. The idea is that I don't know if the company define the slots properly. They are just asking for html 5 banner that are valid. And everything is valid. Is there a way I can reproduce everything ? the page that call the banner and the banner ?

Comment: Well, you would need to create a dummy html page and integrate it with DFP. When you define your slots (or on page level) you need to do the setTargeting I mentioned earlier. That, or you need to test it on the site of the company.

Comment: Here is the definition ... but for a reason that I don't know... the replacement doesn't work ! googletag.pubads().setTargeting('make','bmw').setTargeting('model','x5').setTargeting('condition', ['used']).setTargeting('siteenvironment','www').setTargeting('listing','private');